# Singular and Plural Confusion While Listing Things In A Sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number

Ex. The Gift basket carries mangoes, bananas, pineapples, and a watermelon.

Or, it should be

Ex.The Gift basket carries mangoes, bananas, pineapples, and watermelons

Can I use both singular and plural nouns when adding things to a list?

Comment: If there's only one watermelon, your first sentence is correct.

Comment: Yes, you can have singular and plural nouns in one sentence in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Both your example sentences are correct. But it depends on the exact situation.If there exists a case where there are more than one melon, then you should use 'watermelons' else just go with 'a watermelon'